# How to move and resize a bone in Python such that the head and the tail are at a certain global position?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, transforms

**I want to move and resize a bone by setting the coordinates of the head of the bone and the tail of the bone explicitly.**

For example, let's say that these are my coordinates of my bone head:

```
[181, 151, 67]
```

and that these are the coordinates of my bone tail:

```
[224, 129, 76]
```

I accessed my bone (actually, the armature) in code as follows:

```
right_upper_hand_bone = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
```

Now I want to move and resize `right_upper_hand_bone` such that its head is located at `[181, 151, 67]` and its tail is located at `[224, 129, 76]`.

I Googled around, but I haven't been able to find out how to do this.

**Can anyone tell me how to do this?**

**EDIT:** I'm looking how to reshape the bone such that I explicitly set its head and its tail. Currently, I have a structure where I have a lot of armatures and only one bone within them, but I think it shouldn't be hard to adjust my code to work with one armature with many bones etc.

Comment: Changing the position is easy, referencing it to the global coordinate system is what I don’t know about. Look for that.

Comment: @TheLabCat can you describe what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an armature called "Armature" containing 1 bone named "Bone". Here's a script that will reposition your bone's head and bone's tail to the positions $(181, 151, 67)$ & $(224, 129, 76)$ in global space, respectively. Just adjust `head_pos` & `tail_pos` as needed. Take note that the Origin of your armature will still remain at whatever position it was after you run the script.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

armature = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
bone = armature.data.edit_bones["Bone"]

head_pos = Vector((181, 151, 67))
tail_pos = Vector((224, 129, 76))

matrix_world_inv = armature.matrix_world.inverted()

bone.head = matrix_world_inv @ head_pos
bone.tail = matrix_world_inv @ tail_pos
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. It works for one bone. However, I tried it for multiple bones and it doesn't work. I get an error `KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Bone" not found'` for any other _Bone_ i try to access, even though the names of all of my bones are _Bone_ under different armatures. **Do you know why this code doesn't work for multiple bones?**

Comment: uhm. you asked for one bone. you did not specify exactly what the requirement was. so what exactly do you need? please update your question post. Like is it for alot of armatures with one bone or is it for armatures with many bones? or is it only 1 armature with many bones? please be specific.

Comment: But i think you should be knowledgable enough to figure that out. that's just a matter of simple looping, the heavy lifting of your requirement is basically there. It should be a piece of cake for you to figure out the rest :)

Comment: I agree with you. I think I am able to figure out how to move different bones, regardless of whether they are a part of one armature or multiple armatures. **However, as I stated in my first comment to your post, I can only modify the head and the tail of one bone.** When I try to access the bone in other armatures, I get the key error I mentioned above. I think this has something to do with Edit mode, but I'm not sure.

Comment: you have to return to object mode and then select the next armature then run the script.

Comment: OK, thank you. And can I somehow select the armature in Python instead of clicking on it? I'll Google it, but I'm asking here if you know how to do it. I also updated my original question.

Comment: select it with `armature.select_set(True)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to make it work. Thank you again :)

Comment: you're welcome can u tick the checkmark to mark the answer so we know ur query is resolved.

Comment: Have done so. Thanks again!