# How do I go about animating a rigged 3D model based on 3D keypoints of certain joints in the human body?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, pose-mode

I have 3D coordinates of certain joints in the human body. Those were obtained from a video. I also have a rigged 3D model of the human body.

**What I want is to make the 3D model of the human body move (approximately) the same way as the human in the video.** I think the easiest way for me to do this would be via Python scripting, since I am not new to programming, but I am new to Blender and as such I only have a very vague idea of where to start and what I need to do.

I already tried [setting the head and the tail of a bone explicitly to match the 3D coordinates from the video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283652/how-to-move-and-resize-a-bone-in-python-such-that-the-head-and-the-tail-are-at-a), but this doesn't help me with animating the rigged 3D model, as I do this in Edit mode and from my understanding animation happens in Pose mode.

Here is my (rough) roadmap of what I have to do:

1. Load the 3D coordinates I obtained from the video (I know how to do this)
2. Load the rigged 3D model into Blender (I know how to do this)
3. **Obtain certain information (which?) from the 3D coordinates from the video to move the model in the same way the human moves in the video (this is the hardest part; I don't know how to do this)**.
4. Move the 3D model in Pose mode and keyframe every frame (not sure if this is correct)

**Can someone shed some light on what do I have to do?** I googled a lot, but as you know, Blender is a very intricate piece of software and what I am trying to do is pretty hard, so I'd really appreciate some help.